# a question about expect and tcl

Tags: tcl

I have a question about expect/tcl,
I expect the following

```
expect "class room: classroom 1"
send "classroom"

send "classroom" will return "class room: classroom 1"
```

but this does not match, because the expected matching become

```
class room: classroom 1:
```

how to handle the ":" in expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First piece of advice for developing an expect program: before you `spawn` use this command

```
exp_internal 1
```

That will show you what expect sees, and you can see how it does and does not match your expected patterns.

Next, you can specify regular expressions for your patterns with `expect -re {^pattern$}`. The default pattern mode is glob-style matching, which is documented in Tcl's [string match](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/string.htm#M40) command. Tcl regular expressions are documented [here](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm).

Do you want to code this:

```
send "classroom\r"
expect -re {class room: classroom 1:?}
```

Comment: if the send is class room: \t\tclassroom 1\n, how to expect match it?

Comment: `expect -re {class room:\s+classroom 1}`

Comment: expect -re {class room:\s+classroom 1} does not work, expect -re {class room:\t\tclassroom 1} works.

Comment: what version of expect are you using?

Comment: how to check the expect version?

Answer (score 0):

expect will match any substring

```
send "hello"
expect "he"
```

That will match. Where is the second ":" coming from in yours?

Comment: if the send is class room: \t\tclassroom 1\n, how to expect match it?